# How to check if number is a decimal?

Tags: java, android

I create android app for dividing numbers.

```
int a,b;

int result = a/b;

if (result==decimal){

Log.v ("result","your result number is decimal")

} else {

Log.v ("result","your result number is not decimal")

}
```

How can I check if `result` is a decimal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the modulus operator to check if there is a remainder.

```
if(a % b != 0) Log.v("result", "The result is a decimal");
else Log.v("result", "The result is an integer");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use modulus division to check if a number is a decimal. Let's say you use modulo and divide the number by 1. If it is an integer (math, not java), the remainder should be 0. If it a decimal, it should be anything but 0. Take, for example, this snippet of code:

```
double number = 23.471;
if (number % 1 != 0)
    {
    System.out.print ("Decimal");
    }
else
    {
    System.out.print ("Integer");
    }
```

In this case, it would output "Decimal" because the remainder would not be equal to 0.

Now what would this look like in a full program? The simple program below should allow for number input and then output whether the number is an integer (in math) or decimal.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestClass
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print ("Enter a number: ");
        double number = keyboard.nextDouble ();
        if (number % 1 != 0)
        {
            System.out.print ("Your number is a decimal!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print ("Your number is an integer!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`int` will not hold a decimal, they always take the floor of the result: for example `3 / 5 = 0` as an `int`.  That said you can use modulo (`%`) to determine if decimals are being dropped.

```
if(a % b > 0) { // 3 % 5 = 3
    // Decimal places will be lost
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if the string contains a `.`.

```
String.parseString(decimalNumber).contains(".");
```

Comment: Bad idea some number formats use `.` as a separator eg 1.000 . eg Germany

Comment: @mikek3332002 I'm not 100% sure about that. If I built regex which is matching only for numbers like `9,0` or `9.0`, then an idea of checking only for delimiter is not so bad, we can clearly get an info about if this number was especially decimal or integer. If we convert `9.0` to decimal, then we lost info if it was decimal or integer type, no matters if we check this later with modulo which type is it.