# How to tell if a result is decimal?

Tags: java, jsp

I'm having two float numbers, they can be decimals or not, depending on the operation I want to print the result either with decimal or without.

I'm using String.format to take off the decimal when not needed. However, I have trouble identifying when the result will be decimal. Tried the n1 % n2 > 0 method from a similar question, but when entering for example 6 + 7 the result becomes 13.0 instead of just 13.

Code so far:

```
    float n1 = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("num1").toString().trim());
    float n2 = Float.parseFloat(request.getParameter("num2").toString().trim());

    String res = String.valueOf(n1+n2);

    if(n1 % n2 > 0)
        {
           out.println("It's decimal");
           out.println(n1+n2);
        }else{
           out.println(String.format("%.0f", n1+n2));
        }
```

Comment: Why not parsing the sum as Integer and compare both sums (float and integer).  If they are the same it means the sum is not decimal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if number is a decimal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799943/how-to-check-if-number-is-a-decimal)

Comment: @pseudoAJ tried the answer from that question, but as I said on my edit it didnt work.

Comment: If your question is only about an output display issue (so it will show `13` or `14.5` depending), [there is one approach here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-numbers-to-string-without-unnecessary-decimal-0).

Comment: Please learn the correct terminology.  A real number (or `float`) can be an integer or not--but "decimal" is not a correct term to mean a non-integer.  Your question was rather confusing to me for a while, since "decimal" basically means base 10, and I thought you were asking how to tell whether a number is in base 10.

Comment: @pseudoAJ I don't think this is a duplicate of that question.  That question asks how to tell whether _division between two integers_ gives a non-integer, but there's no division in this example, so the solution is very different.

Comment: The code is somewhat confusing. @Midori_hige do you want to tell if `n1` is divisible by `n2` or if the sum of both numbers has a decimal fraction?

Comment: @dpr if it has a decimal fraction.

Comment: @Midori_hige than I don't understand why you are checking for `n1 % n2 > 0` instead of `(n1+n2)%1 > 0`. If you take a look at my answer this check corresponds to the commented if-statement `res.stripTrailingZeros().scale() > 0`.

Comment: @Midori_hige, has this question been answered for you? If yes, would you mind to accept the most helpful answer to mark this question as solved (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For doing exact math with non-integers (numbers with fractions) in Java you should use `BigDecimal`. This class allows for exact representation of non-integers of arbitrary precision.

That is your code should be changed to:

```
final BigDecimal n1 = new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("num1").toString().trim());
final BigDecimal n2 = new BigDecimal(request.getParameter("num2").toString().trim());

final BigDecimal res = n1.add(n2);
final BigDecimal remainder = n1.remainder(n2);

//if (res.stripTrailingZeros().scale() > 0) {
if (remainder.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) != 0) {
    System.out.println("It's decimal");
    System.out.println(res);
} else {
    final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0f");
    System.out.println(df.format(res));
}
```

The other answer will not give you the correct result, if a user inputs a number larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or lower than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. Casting to `long` will probably yield wrong results due to the precision of `float` that might cause the result to have a decimal fraction even if the input numbers did not...

However I hope you're doing some input validation of the request data. Otherwise you'll most likely get a lot of `NumberFormatExceptions` from your JSP-page.

**UPDATE:**
Updated the code example to check for scale instead of precision.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.round` to tell if a `float` is an integer.  (There are other approaches if your only purpose is to suppress the decimal point for integers when formatting as a string--see KevinO's comment.)

If `f` is a float, `Math.round(f)` returns an `int`, which is `f` rounded to the nearest integer, unless `f` is outside the range of an `int`.  However, if `f` is outside the range of an `int`, then `f` must be an integer, for all practical purposes--if `f` is large enough that it is too big to fit in an `int`, then it's too big to distinguish between values that are less than 1.0 apart (there are fewer bits of precision in a `float` than in an `int`).  So there's no way for `f` to represent a non-integer of that magnitude.

Given that, and assuming that `f` isn't +/- infinity, you can test whether `f` is an integer like this:

```
public boolean isInteger(float f) {
    return f > (float)Integer.MAX_VALUE ||
           f < (float)Integer.MIN_VALUE ||
           f == (float)Math.round(f);
}
```

But please note that even a non-integer could appear as *something*`.000000` when you format it, since the formatter will have to round `f` to a certain number of decimal places when printing.  It depends on what kind of format you're using.

**NOTE:** The above method is a correct way to determine whether a float is an integer, if the `float` is the only information you have.  However, in the context of a larger program, there are other considerations.  If the parameter string is `"2000000000.1"`, when you parse it as a `float` you will get 2000000000, which is an integer, because the `float` doesn't have enough precision to represent the `.1`.  At that point, your `float` will be an integer value, and it's too late for it to know about the `.1`--that information has been lost.  If you don't want to lose that information, then don't use `float` or `double`--use `BigDecimal` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Cast to `int` then back:

```
boolean isDecimal = myFloat != (float)(int)myFloat;
```

Casting to `int` truncates the decimal part.

---

Or, you can use a string approach. Decimals have non-zero digits after the dot, so:

```
boolean isDecimal = String.valueOf(myFloat).matches(".*\\.(?=.*[1-9]).*");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need that for output, the easiest approach is probably to do this with string manipulation:

```
String s = String.format("%.4f", n1 + n2);  // use whatever decimal places you like
s = s.replaceFirst("\\.0*$", "");
System.out.println(s);
```

This will fail if the decimal separator in your Locale is , instead of ., so be careful.

To really check if a double value `x` is integral you can use this test:

```
if (x % 1 == 0) {
    // integral
} else {
    // not integral
}
```